# 2nd graphic board to work with XEN virtualisation?

Tags: xen

I plan to use XEN to work in 2 sytems at the same time. On the 1st screen the main system (Ubuntu 14.04), on the 2nd screen the guest system (Win 7).

Question 1:
Is it a good idea to use a 2nd graphic board?
Win7 should be used for gaming.

Question 2:
Will I need programing knowledge to install and configure XEN for this?

Question 3:
Is it possible to change between the two screens (= 2 different systems) by moving the mouse over the screen border into the next screen?

My experience with XEN is beginner.

Thanks in advance for your advices!

Kind regards
Markus

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

As long as your computer hardware can support running multiple GPUs simultaneously (motherboard has enough PCIe slots, power supply can provide the correct power to the card, etc.), then having multiple GPUs in your system will be **required** to accomplish your goal.

**Question 2**

Not necessarily, but you will **need** to ensure that your motherboard's BIOS has IOMMU enabled and supports GPU passthrough. You will have to check your motherboard manufacturer website to confirm where that setting is located within the BIOS. It's also a good idea to update your BIOS to the latest version if there's one available.

Have a look [here](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_VGA_Passthrough_Tested_Adapters) as well to confirm if your GPU is supported for passthrough in XEN.

In addition to enabling IOMMU, you will need to modify some system files in order for the XEN `pciback` module to seize the secondary GPU for use with the Win7 VM. Generally this can be accomplished by modifying your `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file to look like the following:

```
 xen-pciback passthrough=1 hide=(04:00.0)(04:00.1)
```

I got the `(04:00.0)(04:00.1)` information using the `lspci | grep VGA` command, which provided me with:

```
 04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
```

The `04:00.0` device represents the GPU itself, and the `04:00.1` device is the HDMI audio on your graphics card, which may or may not be listed within `lspci` depending on the model card you're using.

After you update your `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file, be sure to update your initramfs with `update-initramfs -u` otherwise your changes will not persist through a reboot.

**Question 3**

No. Your USB devices are connected to your main system, and booting your Win7 VM with your secondary GPU (even if successful) will not inherently connect your USB devices to the Win7 VM. I personally have not looked into options for sharing USB devices between a host and VM in a XEN system, but [this](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_USB_Passthrough) should help point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps :)